# Application deployment with MinGW and Qt5.6

Tags: c++, qt, deployment, qt5.6

The final goal is to run Qt5.6 based application out of Qt Creator. I've found out that there is a tool `C:\Qt\5.6\mingw49_32\bin\windeployqt.exe`. So I execute it as follows :

```
C:\Qt\5.6\mingw49_32\bin>windeployqt.exe PATH_TO_MY_EXE_FOLDER --release -3dcore -quick -qml -3dquick -3dinput
```

Then I start my app and see that `module QtQuick/QtQuick.Scene3D is not installed`. To fix this, I copy the whole qml folder from `C:\Qt\5.6\mingw49_32\qml` to the folder where my app is.

And I get the following thing on my screen :

> qrc:/main.qml:2:1: plugin cannot be loaded for module
>   "QtQuick.Scene3D": Cannot load library
>   C:\gui\qml\QtQuick\Scene3D\qtqui ckscene3dplugin.dll: ?? ???????
>   ????????? ?????????."

What should I do? Actually, `qtquickscene3dplugin.dll` is in the right folder.

What is the best/easiest way to deploy Qt5.6 based applications?

Answer (score 1):

After half a day of non-stop experiments here is a solution :
1. Copy **all** *.dlls from C:\Qt\5.6\mingw49_32\bin to your bin folder
2. Copy qml and plugin folders from C:\Qt\5.6\mingw49_32 to your bin folder
3. Create qt.conf in your bin folder with the following content :

```
[Paths]
Prefix=.
Plugins=plugins
Qml2Imports=qml
```

After all these steps you will be able to start your application from Windows Explorer. And don't ask me how copying all the DLLs could influence on plugin loading issue :)